# Cannot download phone updates in nokia lumia for windows 10

Tags: update, windows-10-mobile

It shows an phone update for my phone but it is showing 0% from 7AM.It is not moving and my internet connection is fine.What is the problem.Please help me.I could not download apps from store also it is showing 0% from morning for apps also.

Comment: Are you on WiFi or cellular? If on cellular, turn cellular off and switch to WiFi and try again.

Comment: It happens at times,please try closing all the apps that are waiting to update or download and then switch off and on again!

Answer (score 2):

As Windows phone don't allow phone update to be downloaded using **cellular** network,in Cellular network you will see **"Downloading 0%"**,
but as you switch to **Wi-Fi** you will see it downliading.

- In store also, small apps will be downloaded using **Cellular** network,
  for apps with big size like >100 MB, you need **Wi-Fi** Connection.